# How to implement a Camera(onvif) supporting RSTP on own WebPage?

Tags: html, rtsp, ip-camera, onvif

I cant manage to have a view of my Camera on my WebPage!

I tried to implement the Camera with html Code, which didnt Worked!

```
<div>
          <video width="640" height="480" controls>
            <source
              src="rtsp://192.168.0.103:554/onvif"
              type="application/x-rtsp"
            />
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
 </div>
```

This is how it looks like. Then I tried to do it with VLC Media Player. It worked, but the question came, how could I implement the view from VLC Media Player on my Webpage? I googled some things, and I found a tutorial to stream the View of VLC Media Player(Didnt worked). Then I tried some other websites, but they want a lot of money, LOL. So I gave up

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: There are lots of posts around this Browser does Not Support rtsp nativly so you need to transcode it, like using an webrtc Gateway, or mse gateway, Google  for gowebrtc for example